# JAX-WS how to inject SecurityContext outside endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, jax-ws, security-context

I am having problems with jax-ws to inject the SecurityContext. Follow an example below:

```
@JWTTokenNeeded
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/list")
public String list(PublishProductsRequest request, @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {

    User user = userService.getByUserPrincipal(securityContext.getUserPrincipal());
}
```

Using @Context SecurityContext at this point i can receive the informations that i need.

After this i need to call a service that will search some informations, but this informations need to be filtered by customerId and this customerId are inside the User.

The service will be like this:

```
productService.list();
```

Inside the service i will have a DAO, like this:

```
productDao.list();
```

And the select inside Dao like this:

```
select * from products where customer_id = :user.customer_id;
```

So, I want to know if is possible or the best way to inject the user inside the Service(@component) or inside Dao(@Repository).

Of course this is an example, but i have a lot of method that need the informations from user and i don't want to pass it as a param, like:

```
productService.list(user);

productDao.list(user);
```